# What would happen if a same utm parameter is used multiple times in a link?

Tags: google-analytics, utm-parameters

Say I have a link:

```
https://www.example.com/?utm_term=X?utm_term=Y
```

then what would happen in my Google Analytics page? The same with `utm_campaign`, `utm_source`, and `utm_content`.

Comment: With two question marks in there it won't be read as two parameters.  The second `?` Would have to be an `&` to be two parameters.   Right now it is a single parameter with the value `X?utm_term=Y`.

Comment: So `?utm_term=X&?utm_term=Y`?

Comment: You only use ? to start a chain of parameters, then, the separator will be &

Comment: `?utm_term=X&utm_term=Y` would be the correct way to include two parameters.  The question mark separates the query string from the rest of the URL.  Within the query string, the parameters are separated by ampersands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In that case, only one will be taken into account. It will depend on the tool that manages the parameters. By default, Google Analytics uses the last set config, so I will say that the last parameter will override the initial parameter.